# Why do the following tests return false in Scala?

Tags: scala

Both of the following print false. The desired behaviour is for the first to print true and the second to print false. I'm not sure why false always gets printed.

```
def myTest(filter: => Boolean) = () => {

  if (filter) {
    // do something here
    true
  }
  false
}

println(myTest(5 > 3)())
println(myTest(5 > 7)())
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This expression:

```
if (filter) {
  true
}
```

is an expression that returns true when `filter` evaluates to true or Unit `()` otherwise.

This block:

```
{
  expr;
  false
}
```

is a block that evaluates `expr`, discards it, then returns false.

So:

```
{
  if (filter) {
    true
  }
  false
}
```

always returns `false`. Think of `if (filter) { true }` like `expr;`

Answer (score 5):

huynhjl gives the syntactic reason. The phenomenological reason is that you forgot the `else` before the `false`.

```
scala> def myTest(filter: => Boolean) = () => {
     |
     |   if (filter) {
     |     // do something here
     |     true
     |   }
     |   else false
     | }
myTest: (filter: => Boolean)() => Boolean

scala> println(myTest(5 > 3)())
true

scala> println(myTest(5 > 7)())
false
```

Answer (score 2):

The last statement is a false, so it returns false, you'd need an else in the if expression to conditionally execute that statement.

Just like to point out that your filter parameter already resolves a boolean so the if expression is entirely redundant, your construction can be rewritten simply as:

```
def myTest(filter: => Boolean) = () => filter
```

which may lead to further existential questions.

Comment: he has an `// do something here` - comment there.

Comment: ah, the old "do something" thing, that's always a problem